# Pagination and Location search endpoint in Instagram

Tags: instagram

I am using `media/search` endpoint of Instagram API to fetch the pics around a user location. But the problem here is that i am not able to implement pagination.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I also tried having a look at `locations/search` endpoint to get the location id and then thought of using it in to `locations/:id/media/recent` endpoint.

However I failed to understand the mapping of location id in the location/media/recent api as the sample URL given document has no mention of location id.

Sample URL in the doc 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Is there a better way, i can achieve pagination for photos around a location?

Comment: I guess the sample url given in the doc is wrong. The actual url should have been                    https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/<id>/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `/media/search` endpoint doesn't support pagination, see https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram/issues/35